# view.getDrawingCache() not refreshing the original image

Tags: android, view, touch-event

I have 4 images in One screen.
I am trying to overlay bitmap on top of the original image. Below is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (drawIt) {
        drawIt = false;
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        bmpOrignal = view.getDrawingCache();
        bmpGradient = getGradient();
        bmpOverlay = overlay(bmpOrignal, bmpGradient);
        x_limit = view.getLeft() + bmpOrignal.getWidth();
        y_limit = view.getTop() + bmpOrignal.getHeight();
    }

    if (event.getX() > x_limit || event.getY() > y_limit) {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOrignal);
    } else {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOverlay);
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        drawIt = false;

        if (event.getX() > x_limit || event.getY() > y_limit) {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOrignal);
        } else {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOrignal);
        }
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        drawIt = true;

        if (event.getX() > x_limit || event.getY() > y_limit) {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOrignal);
        } else {

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bmpOrignal);
        }
        actionUp(view, event);
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Now among 4 images when i touch on the 1st image,on ACTION_CANCEL the overlay effect will apply and then go off,thats fine, but when i try to do the same thing with 2nd image then the original image of the 1st image will apply to the 2nd image.

Why is it happening, how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this "view.invalidate();"

Comment: @AliImran where do i need to add this ?

Comment: at the end of your touch event.

Comment: yes i tried that too, not working, any other solutions?